# use Double Braces for functions input

Tags: angular

I need to use {{}} for functions Input.
example :

ts :

```
  getValue(value){
    this.myText=value;
    console.log(this.myText);
  }
```

html :

```
  <input type='text'  (click)="getValue('{{text}}')">
```

how do it?

i need to see this in my console:
my console : {{text}}

Comment: I agree with @Reza's answer. But if you still need to pass a variable from controller-template-controller, then you could simply say `(click)="getValue(text)"` where `text = "some value"` in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the literal string `{{text}}` to your method, you can split the first two braces in a string concatenation expression. This way, the Angular compiler will not assume that you are trying to use interpolation (which causes a template parser error):

```
<input type="text" (click)="getValue('{' + '{text}}')" />
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wsnqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

if `text` is available in your html then why not using like this

```
  getValue(){
    this.myText=this.text;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a little more info but if you're asking how do you pass a variable from the template to the .TS then you would just remove the quotes

`<input type='text' (click)="getValue(yourVariableHere)">`

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#statement-context